# Updating Database after Google Checkout Payment

Tags: google-checkout

I am trying to implement Google Checkout in my website.
I have the PHP code sample named "checkout-php-1.3.2" from http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/.

I have followed the instructions and am able to send contents to Google Cart successfully.
The problem is i do not know how to update my website's database after the payment has been made.
I looked a little in the demo code and there is a page responsehandlerdemo.php and there i can  see a lot of notification cases namely

merchant-calculation-callback
new-order-notification
order-state-change-notification
charge-amount-notification

If anybody can provide any help regarding which callback to use and how to parse the xml.
It will be very helpful.

Regards,
Sourav Mukherjee

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of `merchant-calculation-callback` ([ref](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculations_API)), all the other notifications mean *something* to your order processing (everything that has to do **after** successful checkout).

E.g.

- `new-order-notification` - is what it says it is, data representing a new order
- `order-state-change` - orders move into [different states (status)](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Order_States), so this notification notifies you of them

You should go over the [Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing) particularly the [**Notification API**](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API) for details.

I'm not a PHP developer (.Net) but I've seen the sample code and it already [includes XML parsing](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flibrary%2Fxml-processing) for the `notifications` you receive. Once you get to know the API, you'll know when/where in the flow you need to *add your business code* (i.e. database storage, etc.).